# React PWA capturing Keyboard dismiss event

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, webview, progressive-web-apps

I am currently on a react Progressive Web App.After the development of react web app, I did some `ios` development and render my app in `ios` `webview`.
I am running my app in `ios` simulator and problem that I am facing is to capture the keyboard dismiss event.I focus an input, keyboard pops app which pushes up my whole view but when it dismiss, scroll position is not resetting.If there is any approach to solve this issue?

1. How to capture dismiss event of keyboard and call JS function that could reset the scroll position of the parent view?

Comment: it is better if you could drop us some code

Comment: I do not have any specific code snapshot.I am just using material ui Input.My only concern is to trigger the event when done button is clicked on number-pad because it does not trigger any event.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard is handled by the OS (ios), it means that there are no Js events, but there are some work around to let you know when the keyboard is dismissed. 
Those are some suggestions:

- Use [**Focus Events**](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#focus-events) : `onFocus` and `onBlur` on your inputs
- Listen on resize event in the `App` root component
  `window.addEventListener('resize', updateSize);`

Comment: you could post code if you need more help, also please mark the question as resolved if my answer helped you.